# Как не показывать консоль при выполнении os.system()?

Tags: python

Я пробовал изменить расширение файла с .py на .pyw но это не помогло.
Как не показывать консоль при выполнении os.system()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо os.system()
я использовал subprocess

Код:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('cmd command', shell=True)
```

#Именно True а не False

Answer (score 4):

Вывод с консоли?
Самый простой вариант это перенаправить поток вывода в `/dev/null`.
То-есть:  `echo "kek" 1>/dev/null`

Ну или вторым вариантом можно использовать библиотеку `subprocess`, которая делает тоже самое:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)  # No any output
```